# Query a subselection of Sales and Discounts

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce2

Imagine a less than perfect world, where a 'bundles' product type is just a new product with a sale/discount on it.
Would there be any way to query all sales and all products **only related to these** but ignore every other regular "used as intended" sale/discount?

From what I can tell, there is no way to categorise sales/discount, only ways to categorise what the affect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this may not be the best solution, here is a working example for anyone else who has a similar problem (pure twig).

The `saleContainsOtherProduct` variable is an indication that the sale did **NOT** match the criteria of **only related to product type** so in order to check for only related, use `not saleContainsOtherProduct`.
Additionally, this only lists sales, but the code within the loop will work for discounts too, so just repeat with a for loop on `craft.commerce.discounts.getAllDiscounts()`

```
{% set ignoredProductTypes = ['bundles'] %}
{% for sale in craft.commerce.sales.getAllSales() %}
    {% set saleContainsOtherProduct = false %}
    {% set purchasables = [] %}
    {% for id in sale.purchasableIds %}
        {% set purchasable = craft.commerce.purchasables.getPurchasableById(id) %}
        {% if purchasable.product.enabled %}
            {% set purchasables = purchasables | merge([purchasable]) %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for id in sale.categoryIds %}
        {% set category = craft.categories.id(id).one() %}
        {% for product in craft.products().relatedTo(category).all() %}
            {% if product.enabled %}
                {% for purchasable in product.variants %}
                    {% set purchasables = purchasables | merge([purchasable]) %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for purchasable in purchasables if purchasable.product.type.handle not in ignoredProductTypes %}
        {% set saleContainsOtherProduct = true %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```